# PHP compare values not working

Tags: php, html

i have a form that i've made a custom security question for.
It randomizes a question with the code

```
$rand1 = rand ( 1,20 );
$rand2 = rand ( 1,20 );
$randsvar = $rand1 + $rand2;
$securefråga = "Vad blir " . $rand1 . "+" . $rand2;
```

and i then parse it in to my code as

```
$_POST["secure"]
```

after that i convert them both to integers and compare both the converted $randsvar and the form value with eachother with the code

```
$intSecure = intval($secure);
$intRand = intval($randsvar);
if($intSecure == $intRand)
{
  $errorNummer++;
}
else
{
  $secureErr = "wrong answer";
}
```

however even if i type the correct answer it gives me the error message, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$intSecure` contains what?

Comment: save `$randsvar` in session on initial load, then submission, compare the user input

Comment: reload site - new $randsvar

Comment: every time you are reloading the page, or posting to this page to submit an answer, a different random number will be generated each time. As suggested by Ghost, you should save the answer after generating it and compare that one to the answer given. P.S. you should probably avoid using Swedish characters in PHP, ideally change to `$randAnswer` and `$randQuestion`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, hopefully i can now solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions to save the current operation. If submitted, compare the user input to the saved session total. Rough example:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['rand1'] = rand(1, 20);
    $_SESSION['rand2'] = rand(1, 20);
    $_SESSION['randsvar'] = $_SESSION['rand1'] + $_SESSION['rand2'];
} else {
    $input = $_POST['input'];
    if($input == $_SESSION['randsvar']) {
        echo 'correct';
    } else {
        echo 'incorrect';
    }
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <label>
        <?php echo $_SESSION['rand1'] . ' + ' . $_SESSION['rand2'] . ' = '; ?>
        <input type="text" name="input" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </label>
</form>
```